# Placeholder image does not display in product detail page in my custom theme magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I have added placeholder image for products. It displays in admin side, display cart, list page, `minicart` perfect, but does not display in product detail page.

Thanks...

Comment: did you clear cache if not clear cache

Comment: i have clear cash and run content deploy command but still not woking

Comment: Delete all files in pub/static/ folder then deploy static content. If that not working then run "catalog:images:resize" command, hope it'll work

Comment: still not working